# The Brutal-ity of Alien Swarm

Tags: alien-swarm

Playing Alien Swarm on Brutal is nothing short of hilarious, because it is so excessively difficult.
Is there somewhere (steam forums or elsewhere) that has a list of the stats of the aliens when played on Brutal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A *fully manned* brutal mission under default settings features a swarm that has **2.6 times** as much health as it has under a fully manned normal game. The damage dealt is also scaled by 2.6 times.

Additonally both the swarm and the players are faster, although I don't think they're any faster than they are in Insane (that's 20% faster for aliens and 4.8% faster for marines).

---

From `sdk_src\game\shared\swarm\asw_gamerules.cpp`:

```
ConVar asw_difficulty_alien_health_step( /* can be edited from the console */
  "asw_difficulty_alien_health_step",
  "0.2",
   0,
  "How much alien health is changed per mission difficulty level");

// ...

// alters alien health by 20% per notch away from 8 /* that's actually 5 */
float CAlienSwarm::ModifyAlienHealthBySkillLevel(float health)
{
    float fDiff = GetMissionDifficulty() - 5;
    float f = 1.0 + fDiff * asw_difficulty_alien_health_step.GetFloat();

    return f * health;
}

/* ... */

// alters alien health by 20% per notch away from 8 /* that's actually 5 */
float CAlienSwarm::ModifyAlienHealthBySkillLevel(float health)
{
    float fDiff = GetMissionDifficulty() - 5;
    float f = 1.0 + fDiff * asw_difficulty_alien_health_step.GetFloat();

    return f * health;
}
```

...where `GetMissionDifficulty()` returns 13 (for brutal, 10 for insane, 7 for hard, 5 for normal, 3 for easy), [with one point deducted per missing marine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/does-alien-swarm-tune-difficulty-when-play-with-less-than-4-marines) (and a hard lower limit of 2).

(Comments within `/* */` are mine.)

Comment: You can download the source code itself by installing the "Alien Swarm - SDK" item from the often neglected Tools tab of Steam. The game's source code is then in `Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\alien swarm\sdk_src`

Answer (score 1):

I have only found a spreadsheet that list players, classes and aliens data.

Unfortunately `"Aliens"` tab lists only Easy, Normal, Hard and Insane properties. It could be that the author will add Brutal soon, so keep the link.

[Alien Swarm Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AvwbWyZQG0JRdGFnVG9oc3NyXzV4Q1ZMNE1yVnAwMFE&hl=en&authkey=CKr2vQQ#gid=0)

Another possibility is to take a look at the source code, but I do not have it here at the moment, if I find some info later in the code I will edit my answer.